# What kind of "skeleton" does a strict $n$-category admit?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

The [skeleton](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton) of a 1-category is a way to "normalize" it, because

1. Any category is equivalent to its skeleton, and
2. Any equivalence between skeletal categories is an isomorphism.

For strict $n$-categories with $n \geq 2$, it's not clear whether such as "normal form" exists. For instance, one might define a "skeletal 2-category" to be a 2-category where any two equivalent objects are equal and any two isomorphic 1-morphisms are equal. But it's not clear that every 2-category is 2-equivalent to a skeletal one in this sense.

Here my notion  of "$n$-equivalence" is the weak one (as found in the folk model structure): for $n=1$ it's the usual notion, and for $n\geq 2$, an $n$-equivalence of $n$-categories is defined to be an $n$-functor which is surjective on $n$-equivalence classes of objects and such that the functor is an $(n-1)$-equivalence on hom-$(n-1)$-categories (clearly I could start the base case at a lower value of $n$). Here $n$-equivalences of objects are defined in the usual way.

**Question:** Let $n \geq 2$. Is there some analog of the "skeleton" construction for 1-categories which applies to strict $n$-categories?

Such a notion should have the analogs of properties (1) and (2) above. I'd already be happy to understand the case $n=2$.

Comment: Am I right that the tricky part here is the following: even if we wanted to do something a little simpler and just take the "Hom-skeleton" of a 2-category (i.e., form an equivalent 2-category with skeletal Hom-categories), it would require defining the composition functors in a coherent way. Since taking skeletons does not define a functor, it's not at all clear how to make sure our composition functors play nicely.

Comment: @MattFeller I think that's exactly right!

Comment: It seems to me that for any 2-category, one can construct a biequivalent skeletal *bicategory*, but not in general a biequivalent skeletal *strict* 2-category.

Comment: For a proof of the positive statement, see Lemma 2.20 in [your PhD supervisor's PhD thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.1000v2). For the negative statement, recall the cohomological classification of 2-groups (see e.g. [HDA5](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/12/14/12-14abs.html)). A 2-group $G$ is equivalent to a strict & skeletal 2-group iff its "associativity cocycle" (or "Sinh invariant") in $H^3(\pi_0(G),\pi_1(G))$ vanishes.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Do you know of a concrete example of a 2-group in which this Sinh invariant doesn't vanish? Is this nonvanishing a pathological property that most 2-groups in practice don't satisfy?

Comment: @MattFeller No, you should think of it as typical. A general group had no reason to have vanishing third cohomology, and barring that there’s no reason for the invariant to vanish. Every nontrivial third cohomology class determines a distinct 2-group, and in essence, conversely.